# VS Code on save trouble (React import)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have react file:

```
import { CommonTableWithFilterViewDialogsProps, Dialogs } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/Dialogs';
import { ContextWatchState, TProcessProps } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/context/ContextStateValue';
import { TableView, TableViewProps } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/TableView';

import { FilterView } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/FilterView';
import { IReduxForm } from 'app/views/components/_hoc/withReduxForm';
import React from 'react';
import { SelectDataCommonDataModel } from 'app/web/common/data-models';
import { SortingKind } from 'app/common/enums';
import { hasComponentChangesFor } from 'app/common/functions';
```

After saving react file imports shuffles:

```
import { SortingKind } from 'app/common/enums';
import { hasComponentChangesFor } from 'app/common/functions';
import { IReduxForm } from 'app/views/components/_hoc/withReduxForm';
import { ContextWatchState, TProcessProps } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/context/ContextStateValue';
import { CommonTableWithFilterViewDialogsProps, Dialogs } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/Dialogs';
import { FilterView } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/FilterView';
import { TableView, TableViewProps } from 'app/views/modules/_common/components/CommonTableWithFilter/TableView';
import { SelectDataCommonDataModel } from 'app/web/common/data-models';
import React from 'react';
```

Are there any ways to fix that? I dont need to change anything after save.
I've tried to disable 'Format On Save' in Preferences => Settings, and also changed 'settings.json' file:

```
{
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "typescript.format.enable": false,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll": false,
        "source.organizeImports": false,
        "source.sortMembers": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another property in the settings config that's responsible for this. Search for `editor.codeActionsOnSave` and set `source.organizeImports` to false.

Comment: The code posted by the OP already contains the attribute(s) you mentioned. Can you clarify what you mean?